# compress a folder with a password as powershell

Tags: powershell, development-environment

I am looking for a solution to compress a folder with a password as PowerShell

```
$source = "C:\tmp\repertoire"
$destination = "C:\tmp\repertoire.zip"
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source, $destination)
```

Comment: The native .NET Zip file methods (one of which you are using here) do not support password encryption. To get that you would need to install a third-party library or archiver tool (I would recommend 7-Zip).

Comment: Imported formatting